# How to be an Instagram sandbox user for any client in Instagram

Tags: ios, instagram-api

I am building an application with Instagram login. I was able to login and fetch 20 media files as per sandbox rate-limits. Now since I want to fetch the tagged images, I have to invite users to the sandbox after which I can tag their photos and fetch data.

My problem here is I am not able to send sandbox invite.

> I go to **Manage Client > edit > sandbox option > type user name**, enter to invite.
>   It appears as **NOT SAVED** in sandbox user, and the person to whom I am sending the invite is not getting any invite.

Kindly help me as this is my first project on Instagram.

Comment: does that changed to active from pending. In my case, it's still showing me pending. Weird thing user not received any email about sandbox user invitation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Press the "Save Changes" button, it will then change `not saved` to `pending`

Manage Client > Edit > Sandbox tab > type username and Enter > **click "Save Changes"**

Comment: How long it takes for "pending" to "approved" user ?

Comment: @krisrak how long does it take to receive invitation email?, User wan't get since 24 hours.

Comment: it should be immediate, check spam folder

Comment: This is the most stupid interface I have seen in a long time.  When I add someone they should just add them.

Comment: @krisrak As i type username and press enter, all the other 9 users are automatically populated with my developer account username(which is already the admin), and when i click save changes, it says cannot add admin as he is already added. What can be the issue?

Comment: I don't see how you guys can add users, I don't even have a button to add or an input field to start typing

Answer (score 9):

You need to go to Manage Client - Edit - Sandbox - type in the username and Enter as the accepted answer states, but I'd like to also add how to accept the invitation as I had to look around a bit for this, on the receiving account, log in and go to

https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Click Sandbox Invites at the top menu, there your invite will be waiting for you to accept, there are no emails sent for my test accounts, hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

Just go to Sandbox Invites and press Accept in your test account Developer Documentation page

Answer (score 2):

enable to see **Accept Invitation** the other user accept the invitation must:

1. go to https://www.instagram.com/developer/
2. Register your application.
3. Fill in whatever is being ask ex. your website can be http://localhost
4. after registering go to **Sandbox Invites**.
5. then you can see and accept the invitation.