# instagram sandbox user invite sent but where does the user accept it?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, instagram, instagram-api

I am consuming the instagram and have been able to sent the invite to my second user.
However when the second user logs in to this link:

```
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=XXXXXXX&redirect_uri=yyyyyyyyyyy://&response_type=token
```

they just get

`{"code": 403, "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "error_message": "You are not a sandbox user of this client"}`

I have also logged in as that user to the official instagram app and still I have no place to accept the invite. How do the sandbox users accept their invites to use my app?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765854/how-to-be-an-instagram-sandbox-user-for-any-client-in-instagram

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765854/how-to-be-an-instagram-sandbox-user-for-any-client-in-instagram

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out.

[I did read the doc:](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/) where it says

> "To manage the list of sandbox users for a given app, you can go to
>   the Sandbox tab in your client configuration screen. There you will be
>   able to add and remove the sandbox users for your app, up to a maximum
>   of 10 users. Note that the admin of the app is always a sandbox user,
>   so you can effectively add up to 9 additional 'sandbox users'.
>
> After adding users to the list, they will have to accept your
>   invitation before actually becoming sandbox users. To accept the
>   invitation, they can go to the 'Sandbox Invites' button on the top bar
>   of the developer site. In the 'Sandbox Invites' page people can accept
>   or reject invitations, and also stop being sandbox users for a given
>   app."

I tried it but it wasn't working - probably due to a delay. After 5 minutes, I was able to see the invite and get through.

Comment: Is it true today? I can't get it to work. Moreover, Instagram doesn't recognize any of the sandbox users in my sandbox app.

Comment: Hm....I trying to invite some users to test my app, they accepting, but still get 403 error