# Inviting the other sandbox users

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to develop my  `sandbox` app using `instagram` API. Based on documentation, I can invite up to 9 sandbox users to make a network.
I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765854/how-to-be-an-instagram-sandbox-user-for-any-client-in-instagram).
The problem is, I don't know **what are the usernames of sandbox users?**

Or alternativly, how can i find `list of avalible sanbox users?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invite Instagram users you know, if you just send to random people they may not know or may not accept. Better to invite your friends who use Instagram.